# Type incoherence between the register() function of react-hook-form and the native input types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm working on a React project using TypeScript and [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/). In some place I use the given function [register()](https://react-hook-form.com/api#register) that have to be used like that (according to the official documentation):

```html
<input
  name="test"
  ref={
    register({
      required: true
    })
  }
/>
```

The problem I'm facing here is that this function is typed in such a way that it return `void`:

```js
(Ref, validateRule?) => void
```

But the attribute `ref` of the native `input` tag has to be of type:

```
string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined
```

So naturally TypeScript throws me this error:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'

Do you have an idea of how I can use this library while respecting the types? Is this a mistake on the part of the library itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found already solved answers on the Github related project : https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+register+void+is+not+assignable+to+type

Looks like depending on what you plug on the `ref` prop. Maybe consider init this on a useEffect ?

Refer to this issue : https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/598 redirect himself to the documentation for Controlled components (could be your case). You should probably use the `useEffect` way like :

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const { register } = useForm()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    register({ name: "nameOfMyInput" })
  })

  return (
    <input name="nameOfMyInput" />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all this informations. I recommend you to add directly the path to the right [issue](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/598) and to also provide an example of what the solution will. It's avoid 'external link only' anwers ;) When it's done I will `validate` and `upvote` your answer.

Comment: The fact is I'm not sure which is the exact one in your case. But I can assume one :). Edit incoming